Asian centered movie with scene of three asian women tortured by police/soldiers
What I remember from this movie (in the late 90s or perhaps early 2000s) was that it centered on an Asian woman (I think a young woman in her 20's or maybe 30's). I don't know which country, but it was set in an Asian country.
Now the titular scene first has the three woman tied to a pole. The police/soldiers put honey/sweets in the women's feet and insects bite their feet. Later, the police/soldiers then put a snake/eel in their cleavages and two of the women become very frightened. Afterwards, the protagonist is released for some reason. The whole scene is set during the day, and what looks to be a prison.
Another scene in the movie, during the night, has the protagonist witness a couple of men shoot and kill an English teacher. 

Do you remember the approximate year of release? Or where you saw it?

Late 90 or perhaps early 2000's

Oliver Stone's Heaven & Earth (1993) (IMDB) contains a torture scene involving insects and snakes.
Protagonist (Vietnamese woman Le Ly) is tortured by South Vietnamese police.




@Walt Thanks for your edit
